# how to silence sklearn warning on _logistic regression

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, warnings, logistic-regression

Regression didn't work because data don't correlate. I understand I could increase the number of iterations.

However, in this case I don't want to see the following warning:

lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py:939: ConvergenceWarning:

lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):
STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.

Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html.
Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to shut down warnings:

```
from warnings import simplefilter

# ignore all warnings
simplefilter(action='ignore')
```

see also [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-fix-futurewarning-messages-in-scikit-learn/)